# OWIN/Katana selfhost generic handler (ashx) not invoked

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I'm trying to use OWIN/Katana selfhosted console app with my generic ASHX handler, but just can't get it working. Is that even supported? I have it registered in app.config with path `MyHandler.axd` as I'd do for an ASP.NET application (and where it works with this equivalent setup):

```
 <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <add name="MyHandler" path="MyHandler.axd" verb="*" type="My.AssemblyName.Handlers.MyAsyncHandler, My.AssemblyName, Culture=neutral" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

The handler implementation (that is not invoked):

```
 namespace My.AssemblyName.Handlers
 {
     public class MyAsyncHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler
     {
        public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            // code that is not hit
        }
    }
}
```

My `Startup` class is implemented like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("MyHandler.axd", "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("MyHandler.ashx", "{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

And the application is invoked with

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

These are my installed NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost
- Microsoft.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
- Also Note that my handler is **HttpTaskAsyncHandler**, so I'm also referencing `System.Web.dll`

**EDIT**: I see handlers are configured [here with Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-owin) for the ASP.NET Host (Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb). How's that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no support for running any System.Web components in Katana selfhost. Only the WebApi, SignalR, and other OWIN compatible frameworks are supported by Katana selfhost.

Comment: yeah, thought so. It's actually really an IIS thing. Thanks!